# Printing variables including functions from Makefile and/or variable introspection

Tags: function, makefile, multiline, introspection

If you iterate over .VARIABLES and print each, any true variable can be printed correctly with the following rule:

```
print_variables: $(foreach V,$(.VARIABLES),print-$(V)) .phony_explicit
print-%: .phony_explicit; @echo "$* = \"$($*)\""
.PHONY: .phony_explicit ...
```

A 0- or 1-line function will still work, but any more will result in `Syntax error: Unterminated quote string`. Just one multiline function will break the entire `print_variables` rule. As a workaround, I have added `;\` to each line in my function definitions, but that won't fix existing multiline functions (either via includes from this makefile or via other makefiles including this one.) What can I do? Is there a container of just function variables, or a way to test if a variable is a function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple minimal example would be easier to understand; this has nothing to do with `.VARIABLES`, pattern rules, etc. (and I'm not sure what the point of the `.phony_explicit` prereq is..)

```
define F
foo
bar
endef

print: ; echo "F = $(F)"
```

will show the problem:

```
echo "F = foo
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

This is because when make sees a variable that contains newlines in a recipe, it assumes that the newlines mean you want the lines of the variable to become lines in the recipe.

First in general you should use single-quotes around strings you send to the shell, unless you need the shell to expand them; it won't help in this situation but in general it's much safer.

There's no way to undo that, really.  You have a number of options.

The first is to not use echo but instead use the make function `info`:

```
print-F: ; $(info F = "$(F)")
```

yields:

```
F = "foo
bar"
```

Another option is to use `subst` to replace the newlines with some other value.  The new value cannot itself contain explicit newlines, but you can ask the *shell* to print a newline for you:

```
# Create a variable containing a single newline
# Note this must contain TWO newlines!
define NL


endef

print-F: printf 'F = "$(subst %,%%,$(subst $(NL),\n,$(F))"\n'
```

Yields:

```
printf 'F = "foo\nbar"\n'
F = "foo
bar"
```

One final option is to convert your makefile to use the `.ONESHELL` feature, but I assume that's a step too far just to get this debugging output available :).

Comment: Adding `phony_explicit` to `.PHONY` means that adding `phony_explicit` to any other target makes that target phony as well. (In other words it allows you to make phoniness a prerequisite to your target rather than making your target a prerequisite to `.PHONY`.) As a result the phoniness of a target is declared in the same place as the target itself. Otherwise you would either have to jump back and forth to your `.PHONY` target while reading/writing phony targets elsewhere, or re-target `.PHONY` next to each applicable target. I'm not aware of a more elegant solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, by `print-F: echo 'F = "$(subst $(NL),; ,$(F))"'`, did you mean to add a semicolon or newline after `print-F:` ?

Also, here's where I believe I learned that phony trick.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38803814/1043529

Comment: I just add a `.PHONY` next to each target; the extra line doesn't bother me.  But YMMV.  I didn't mean to add a newline; you can't really do that with echo but that gives me an idea: you can use printf.  I'll update my answer.