# .PHONY pattern rule: match pattern with leading slash

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to simplify a Makefile.  In that, I tried to have a pattern rule for removing files:

```
.PHONY:
rm-%:
        rm $*
```

where % would contain the name of the file (usually the absolute path with a leading slash).
And then I just state that rm-/some/file is a dependency of `make uninstall`, and expect make to match this pattern rule.

However, it bite me.  I did some tests and realized that the problem was that a leading slash did not match that pattern rule:

```
~/src/test$ cat Makefile 
.PHONY:
a-/%:
    $(info /$*)

.PHONY:
b-%:
    $(info $*)

.PHONY:
foo: a-/as/d
    @:

.PHONY:
bar: b-/as/d
    @:

~/src/test$ make foo
/as/d
~/src/test$ make bar
make: *** No rule to make target 'b-/as/d', needed by 'bar'.  Stop.
~/src/test$
```

Why do I need to specify that leading slash in the pattern rule (but not other slashes)?

The GNU make documentation says this:

> the ‘%’ matches any nonempty substring, while other characters match
> only themselves

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro

---

**EDIT:** Fix some typos about `.PHONY:`, use a suffix instead of a prefix as suggested in the answers/comments, and test further:

As I initially suspected, `.PHONY:` is doing something weird:

```
~/src/test/$ tree a b c d
a
└── a
b
└── b
c
└── c
d
└── d

0 directories, 4 files
```

```
~/src/test$ cat Makefile 
%-rmdir:
    rmdir $(@D)

%-rm:
    rm $*

.PHONY: ./a/.-rmdir
./a/.-rmdir: ./a/a-rm

.PHONY: ./b/-rmdir
./b/-rmdir: ./b/b-rm

./c/.-rmdir: ./c/c-rm

./d/-rmdir: ./d/d-rm

.PHONY: foo
foo: ./a/.-rmdir ./b/-rmdir ./c/.-rmdir ./d/-rmdir
    $(info foo)
```

```
~/src/test$ make foo
rm a/a
rm b/b
rm c/c
rmdir c
rm d/d
rmdir d
foo
```

Comment: Just to note, I don't know what you mean in your question title by `.PHONY pattern rule`, but you are not declaring _anything_ `.PHONY` here since its prerequisite list is empty.  But, phoniness is not related to your question anyway.

Comment: @MadScientist D'oh, that was a typo.  Anyway, I just added that info just in case it triggered some different behavior, but I guess it doesn't.

Comment: @MadScientist, could you review the tests I added?  It looks like .PHONY: is doing something...

Comment: Looks like I'm having this problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3096699/6872717
If someone needs to know, I could only find that behavior with `make -p`.  The other debug options like `--trace` or `-d` were useless in this case.

Comment: When asking please explain clearly what is wrong with the results you show (what you expected to be different).  It takes a lot of time to suss out the problem you're trying to solve on our own.  But yes, as that other question mentions, a `.PHONY` target is never eligible to be looked up with implicit rules.  That's one of the primary reasons to declare a target `.PHONY`: to improve performance.  You can use the `FORCE` trick if all you care about it ensuring rebuilds without improving performance.

Comment: My original comment about "not doing anything" only referred to your initial question/ makefile, where the `.PHONY` target had no prerequisites.  That is a no-op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to examine the section on [How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) where you will find this text:

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does
> not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
> before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix.

(and more detail about how this works).

Comment: So, I'd need to create rules of the form %.rm and %.rmdir to workaround this, right?  Where % is the name of the file or dir to be removed

Comment: That should work.  Or, include the `/` as you did: by putting a `/` in the pattern you remove the special case handling above.

Comment: That (including the leading /) did bite me again: rm-./as/d/f didn't match any of the rules

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation and @MadScientist answer, this is [how patterns match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html). But workaround is very simple: replace your prefix rules with suffix rules and this directory mangling will not stand in the way.

Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: %-clean
%-clean:
        $(info $*)

.PHONY: foo
foo: /as/d-clean
        @:

.PHONY: bar
bar: ./as/d-clean
        @:
```

Output:

```
$ make foo
/as/d
$ make bar
as/d
```

BTW. Please note that `.PHONY:` requires target name, it does not automagically apply to the target that follows.